# IoT Edge V2 C2D messages handling

Tags: azure-iot-edge

Is IoT Edge V2 capable of receiving and handling C2D (not direct methods) messages?

If yes, how does it handle them? Which module gets the message?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no receiving D2C messages supporting found either from [documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/module-development) and [GitHub code](https://github.com/Azure/iot-edge). Currently, only receiving direct method from cloud on the module is valid.

This is a feature question you can submit it to [Azure IoT Edge feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/907045-azure-iot-edge). Share it here so other people needs can vote it up.